# How to make all controller routes to default to index in the routes.php file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some controllers like **home** and **welcome**, now in my routes.php i have set the default controller to be:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/index';
```

This works fine, now I want for all other controller to go to the default function of index without typing index in the url like.

```
http://localhost/codeigniterapp/index.php/welcome/
```

To do that I did this in the routes.php:

```
$route['welcome'] = "welcome/index";
$route['home'] = "home/index";
$route['xxx'] = "xxx/index";
```

Now I don't want to be doing that for every controller but would want something like a (:any) wildcart i saw in their [userguide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).
I tried:

```
$route['(:any)'] = '(:any)/index';
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Removing the index.php file
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes I looked into that, but it doesn’t still solve my problem.

Comment: do you get any errors or anything? You may have to allow mod_rewrite on apache https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04